# Форма select в Thymeleaf не получается

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, spring-data

Пытаюсь создать форму фильтров:
[image: Форма]

Предпоследняя - строка в фильтрации input , если в нее вписать "true" , и отправить запрос, то таблица будет содержать только проданные машины, если false то наоборот, если пусто - то все машины.

Пытаюсь создать форму с заранее выбранными опциями (Последняя строка в фильтрации) Но не врубаюсь как...

Вот код :

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <br>
                <h3>Filtration</h3>
                <form th:action="@{/management}" th:object="${param.sold}" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input th:value="${param.brand != null} ? ${param.brand}" name="brand" placeholder="Brand"
                               class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input th:value="${param.model != null} ? ${param.model}" name="model" placeholder="Model"
                               class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input th:value="${param.minYear != null} ? ${param.minYear}" name="minYear"
                               placeholder="Min Year"
                               class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input th:value="${param.maxYear != null} ? ${param.maxYear}" name="maxYear"
                               placeholder="Max Year"
                               class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input th:value="${param.minMileage != null} ? ${param.minMileage}" name="minMileage"
                               placeholder="Min Mileage"
                               class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input th:value="${param.maxMileage != null} ? ${param.maxMileage}" name="maxMileage"
                               placeholder="Max Mileage"
                               class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input th:value="${param.minPrice != null} ? ${param.minPrice}" name="minPrice"
                               placeholder="Min Price"
                               class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input th:value="${param.maxPrice != null} ? ${param.maxPrice}" name="maxPrice"
                               placeholder="Max Price"
                               class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input th:value="${param.sold != null} ? ${param.sold}" name="sold"
                               placeholder="Sold"
                               class="form-control form-control-sm mr-sm-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                                                <select th:field="${param.sold}" >
                        <option th:value="''">All</option>
                        <option th:value="true">Sold</option>
                        <option th:value="false">No sold</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Filter</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Также добавлю остальной код, вдруг поможет :

Контроллер:

```
@GetMapping()
public String index(Model model
        , @AuthenticationPrincipal SecurityUser user
        , @RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams
) {
    Integer pageNumber = Integer.parseInt(requestParams.getOrDefault("page", "1"));
    CarFilter carFilter = new CarFilter(requestParams);

    model.addAttribute("cars", carService.getCarWitPagingAndFiltering(carFilter.getSpec(), pageNumber));
    model.addAttribute("filterDef", carFilter.getFilterDefinition().toString());
    model.addAttribute("user", user.toString());
    return "management/index";
}
```

CarSpec.java

```
public class CarSpec {
    public static Specification<Car> brandContains(String filterBrand) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder)
                -> criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("brand"), "%" + filterBrand + "%");
    }

    public static Specification<Car> modelContains(String filterModel) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder)
                -> criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("model"), "%" + filterModel + "%");
    }

    public static Specification<Car> mileageLesserThanOrEq(Integer value) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder)
                -> criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("mileage"), value);
    }

    public static Specification<Car> mileageGreaterThanOrEq(Integer value) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder)
                -> criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("mileage"), value);
    }

    public static Specification<Car> yearLesserThanOrEq(Integer value) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder)
                -> criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("year"), value);
    }

    public static Specification<Car> yearGreaterThanOrEq(Integer value) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder)
                -> criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("year"), value);
    }

    public static Specification<Car> priceLesserThanOrEq(Integer value) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder)
                -> criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("price"), value);
    }

    public static Specification<Car> priceGreaterThanOrEq(Integer value) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder)
                -> criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("price"), value);
    }

    public static Specification<Car> soldContains(String filterSold) {
        Boolean value = Boolean.parseBoolean(filterSold);
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder)
                -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("sold"), value);
    }


}
```

CarServiceImpl.java

```
@Override
public Page<Car> getCarWitPagingAndFiltering(Specification<Car> specification, Integer page) {
    if (page < 1) {
        page = 1;
    }
    return carRepository.findAll(specification, PageRequest.of(page - 1, 10));
}
```

CarFilter.java

```
@Getter
public class CarFilter {
    private Specification<Car> spec;
    private StringBuilder filterDefinition;

    public CarFilter(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.spec = Specification.where(null);
        this.filterDefinition = new StringBuilder();
        if (map.containsKey("brand") && !map.get("brand").isEmpty()) {
            String brand = map.get("brand");
            spec = spec.and((CarSpec.brandContains(brand)));
            filterDefinition.append("&brand=").append(brand);
        }
        if (map.containsKey("model") && !map.get("model").isEmpty()) {
            String model = map.get("model");
            spec = spec.and((CarSpec.modelContains(model)));
            filterDefinition.append("&model=").append(model);
        }
        if (map.containsKey("minMileage") && !map.get("minMileage").isEmpty()) {
            int minMileage = Integer.parseInt(map.get("minMileage"));
            spec = spec.and(CarSpec.mileageGreaterThanOrEq(minMileage));
            filterDefinition.append("&minMileage=").append(minMileage);
        }
        if (map.containsKey("maxMileage") && !map.get("maxMileage").isEmpty()) {
            int maxMileage = Integer.parseInt(map.get("maxMileage"));
            spec = spec.and(CarSpec.mileageLesserThanOrEq(maxMileage));
            filterDefinition.append("&maxMileage=").append(maxMileage);
        }
        if (map.containsKey("minYear") && !map.get("minYear").isEmpty()) {
            int minYear = Integer.parseInt(map.get("minYear"));
            spec = spec.and(CarSpec.yearGreaterThanOrEq(minYear));
            filterDefinition.append("&minYear=").append(minYear);
        }
        if (map.containsKey("maxYear") && !map.get("maxYear").isEmpty()) {
            int maxYear = Integer.parseInt(map.get("maxYear"));
            spec = spec.and(CarSpec.yearLesserThanOrEq(maxYear));
            filterDefinition.append("&maxYear=").append(maxYear);
        }
        if (map.containsKey("minPrice") && !map.get("minPrice").isEmpty()) {
            int minPrice = Integer.parseInt(map.get("minPrice"));
            spec = spec.and(CarSpec.priceGreaterThanOrEq(minPrice));
            filterDefinition.append("&minPrice=").append(minPrice);
        }
        if (map.containsKey("maxPrice") && !map.get("maxPrice").isEmpty()) {
            int maxPrice = Integer.parseInt(map.get("maxPrice"));
            spec = spec.and(CarSpec.priceLesserThanOrEq(maxPrice));
            filterDefinition.append("&maxPrice=").append(maxPrice);
        }
        if (map.containsKey("sold") && !map.get("sold").isEmpty()) {
            String sold = map.get("sold");
            spec = spec.and((CarSpec.soldContains(sold)));
            filterDefinition.append("&sold=").append(sold);
        }

    }
}
```

Помогите)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился :

```
                <select th:name="sold">
                    <option th:value="''">All</option>
                    <option th:value="${'true'}">Sold</option>
                    <option th:value="${'false'}" name="sold">No sold</option>
                </select>
```